# YouCompleteme unavailable : no module named future

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

i am trying to install the YouCompleteMe Plugin in vim using Vundle but i get this error message : YouCompleteme unavailable : no module named future

i have vim 7.4.1910 and python 3.5.2 but i don't know if vim was built to support python3

Comment: :echo has('python') || has('python3')

Comment: I'm getting the same error on Fedora 24. @P4C the output from your command for is 1 (for `has('python')`)

Answer (score 8):

its that your modules are not updated or future module is not found.
to fix this. if you are using ubuntu then first go to

```
$ cd ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe && git submodule update --init --recursive
```

this will update all the modules in youcompleteme

Comment: Also running the `install.py` script in the YouCompleteMe folder helped for me

Comment: I had to do both: `cd ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe ; git submodule update --init --recursive` and `./install.py`.  Then everyone was fine.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and fixed it by running `pip install future`. You may have to do this with `sudo`.

Comment: sudo -H pip install future

Comment: `-H` is the short version of `--set-home` longopt. Sudo required me to specify the -H flag in order to install this module.

Comment: @JennyT-Type it is not a good idea to use sudo with pip.